# Invoke-Sqlcmd : Duplicate column names are not permitted in SQL PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I've spitted [Glenn Berry's Performance Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHhz0.png) in 14 queries but one of them (number 9) is not working.

This is my PowerShell code:

```
#Provide SQLServerName
$SQLServer ="localhost"
#Provide Database Name 
$DatabaseName ="master"
#Prompt for user credentials 
$credential = Get-Credential 

$Query1= "-- 09 Index Sizes
-- Note: THIS IS SLOW as it reads index blocks. SAMPLED is not that high, but watch for prod I/O impact if using 'DETAILED'
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
 Object_name(i.object_id) AS TableName
   ,i.index_id, name AS IndexName
   ,i.type_desc
   ,ips.page_count, ips.compressed_page_count
   ,CAST(ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent as DECIMAL(5,1)) [fragmentation_pct]
   ,CAST(ips.avg_page_space_used_in_percent as DECIMAL(5,1)) [page_space_used_pct]
   ,ips.index_depth, ips.page_count ,ips.forwarded_record_count, ips.record_count
  FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED') AS ips -- or SAMPLED
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON ips.object_id = i.object_id AND ips.index_id = i.index_id
where ips.page_count > 1
ORDER BY ips.record_count desc;"

Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Database $DatabaseName -ServerInstance $Server -Credential $credential -Query $Query1 | Format-Table
```

[image]

The error returned says:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Duplicate column names are not permitted in SQL PowerShell. To repeat a column, use a column alias for the duplicate
column in the format Column_Name AS New_Name.
At C:\Users\FrancescoM\Desktop\CSV\Test.ps1:23 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Database $DatabaseName -ServerInstance $Server -Crede ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SyntaxError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DuplicateColumnNameErrorMessage,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Not sure what is the duplicate column because if I run the query called into the PowerShell script on SSMS I don't see any duplicate column:

[image]

Comment: I think this shouldn't be closed: I don't see any other post on StackOverflow talking about the error: `Invoke-Sqlcmd : Duplicate column names are not permitted in SQL PowerShell.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrived at home I formatted the query in a decent way and thanks to Notepad++, after clicking on each column I found out that `ips.page_count` was called twice.

So there was indeed a column called twice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following parameter for the Invoke-Sqlcmd command.

-OutputSqlErrors $False

It will suppress the error.

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you have duplicate column names in resultset of the query.
invoke-sqlcmd : Duplicate column names are not permitted in SQL PowerShell

Suppose you used below query as to see result-set in your invoke-sqlcmd query-

select test, * from  testtable

Now the test column will be duplicate in the result and invoke sqlcmd execution  will fail.

To Resolve this use like this-
select test as testColumn, * from  testtable